# PHP date and time code of some error

Tags: php, datetime

```
$strStart = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time() - 3600);
$strEnd   = $row['DateAndTime'];
$dteStart = new DateTime($strStart);
$dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd);
$dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
echo $dteDiff->format("%d days, %h hours, %i mints");
```

This code is working well in the local server, but it is not working at all in the live server..the page is going black every time.  May be, the problem is in the 5th line. But,  I am not sure. How I can I solve the problem ?

Comment: maybe `$row['DateAndTime']` is undefined at your live server? worth to check. also if you have access to logs `/var/log/apache2` check them also

Comment: put error reporting at the top of the page.

Comment: Please check timezone setup at live server, may be it different timezones ( assuming $row['DateAndTime'] is posted data ) creating issue .

Comment: How can i put error reporting at the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be in `$row['DateAndTime']` variable.
Make shure if it's has correct datetime value.
may be you can insert some fromat check, like:

```
preg_match(
    '~[0-9]{4,4}-[0-9]{2,2}-[0-9]{2,2} [0-9]{2,2}:[0-9]{2,2}:[0-9]{2,2}~ui',
    '2015-02-02 03:44:11'
)
```

and h - is hours in 12-hour format;
may be replace it with H - 24-hour format?

To enable all errors add these in the beginning of the script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```